# Are there any analyses of GA tie-down failures?

Tags: aircraft-storing

After a big harbor storm, there are frequently analyses of why boats break free of their moorings. This information is used to improve upon best practices, resulting in fewer boats breaking free and being destroyed.

Is there something similar for aviation? I see so many FBOs that have tie-downs made with inappropriate rope, oftentimes polypropylene (which is highly UV sensitive and rapidly loses strength when left outside). On a personal note, I also wonder if the [taut-line hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut-line_hitch) frequently used to tie-down airplanes for long periods of time will keep from slipping in a blow.

I've also seen airplane tie-down rings which are worn through over the years, by a combination of friction with ropes and, in the case of tail tie-downs, grinding on runways. And I've been shown eye bolts distended under the load of big storms.

I'd love to read up on what has historically been good and bad practices for securing planes.

Comment: All I've seen is a video comparing portable temporary tiedowns using a tractor and force gauge to pull them out. IIRC he said they need to have to resist about 1000lbs to be effective in storms. The winner was a gadget that used 3 large spade blades driven into the ground. It provides a bit of insight on what permanent tie downs need to achieve. Should be on youtube.

Comment: Do you have a sense of how often do ground anchors fail? I feel like that's a lot rarer than ropes, knots, and tie-down rings failing. There are certain exceptions to this, like a fly-in where everyone is in the grass with the dog-chain screws you can buy at a hardware store.

Comment: Most tie down anchors at airports are either a tripod of rebar or steel pipes driven into the ground then welded together, or sonotubes with concrete. In those cases it's always going to be the rope that fails. The screw type tiedowns are quite useless in a serious wind storm, only good for a few hundred pounds, depending on soil.